# Как оптимизировать столкновения шаров?

Tags: c++, оптимизация, cuda, распараллеливание

Я только начинаю изучать cuda.
Пишу программу для столкновения шаров в 3д плоскости, создаю функцию add для перебора столкновений шара номер id с остальными шарами. Программа работает верно, однако очень долго. Можно ли тут что-то исправить?

```
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string> 
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory.h>
using namespace std;
#define n 65536

__global__ void add(double* mx, double* my, double* mz, int* mr,int* m)
{   
    int bid = blockIdx.x;
    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    int id = bid * blockDim.x+ tid;
    // это верное определение id
    float x1 = mx[id];
    float y1 = my[id];
    float z1 = mz[id];
    
    for (int i = id; i <= n; i++) {
        if ((pow((pow((mx[i] - x1), 2) + pow((my[i] - y1), 2) + pow((mz[i] - z1), 2)), 0.5) <= mr[i] + mr[id]) && id!=i) {
            m[id] = id;
        }
    }
    
}

double mx[n];
double my[n];
double mz[n];
int m[n];
int mr[n];
//const int n = sizeof(mx) / sizeof(float);
double* dev_mx, * dev_my, * dev_mz;
int* dev_m;
int* dev_mr;
long long* dev_mid;
int main() {
    // заполнение массива
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        mx[i] = i;
        my[i] = i;
        mz[i] = i;
        mr[i] = 1;
    }
    // выделение памяти на девайсе
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_mx, n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_my, n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_mz, n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_mr, n * sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_m, n * sizeof(int));
    //cudaMalloc((void**)&dev_n, sizeof(int));

    // копирование переменных на девайс
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mx, mx, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_my, my, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mz, mz, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_mr, mr, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(dev_m, m, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //cudaMemcpy(dev_n, &n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    
    // передача данных в функцию
    int dev = 0;
    cudaDeviceProp deviceProp;
    cudaGetDeviceProperties(&deviceProp, dev);

    unsigned int maxThreads = deviceProp.maxThreadsPerBlock;
    cout << maxThreads << endl;
    add << <n / maxThreads, maxThreads >> > (dev_mx, dev_my, dev_mz, dev_mr, dev_m);



    // вернуть данные

    cudaMemcpy(&m, dev_m, n * sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << i << " " << m[i] << endl;
    }
    
    cudaFree(dev_mx);
    cudaFree(dev_my);
    cudaFree(dev_mz);
    cudaFree(dev_mr);
    cudaFree(dev_m);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Пробовал менять кол-во блоков и тредов, ничего не меняется.

Comment: И уж точно не надо считать квадратный корень! лучше правую часть в квадрат возводить...

Comment: Очень долго - ¿это сколько? И давайте осмысленные названия переменным.

Comment: Вы проверяете столкновения  - каждый с каждым. Это O(n^2). Если есть ограничения на радиус шаров, то можно применить разные оптимизации, с предварительной сортировкой шаров, чтобы чтобы проверять не все пары. Вплоть до O(n*log(n)).

Comment: Вам надо обработать 65 тысяч шаров?

Comment: Да это программа под симуляцию поведения газов 65000 это минимум